# Why does Qt have a 'Q' version of standard C++ objects (e.g. QVector, QString, etc.)?

Tags: c++, qt

Why must Qt have a 'Q' version for many standard objects/data structures in C++? Does the reasoning spawn from one source (i.e. there needs to be attached meta data for formatting purpose), or is it something that just depends on the case (e.g. QString allows for more language settings and QVectors allow for 'whatever')?

Thanks!

Comment: The biggest reason is probably backward compatibility.

Comment: They raise a few reasons on the [Container Classes documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/containers.html)

Comment: When it Rome do as the Romans do. They are not just "versions of std::stuff". Many of them are tightly coupled with how Qt works internally. Many of them actually predate std::stuff, and some of them have actually been rendered obsolete by recent std::stuff, as C++ finally caught up with those features.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Qt containers precede STL containers, original versions (in Qt 1 or Qt 2 or something) were created when there were no standard C++ alternatives. Also, adaptation of the STL for all (at that time) supported compilers was gradual, and Qt was geared toward being cross-platform, so keeping its own implementation guaranteed it would work the same everywhere. And getting rid of the Qt's own types now, for next major Qt version, would mean impossible amount of porting work, so such a new version would effectively be dead on arrival.
2. Qt containers are actually different, they use implicit data sharing with Copy-on-write semantics and reference counting. Advantages and disadvantages of this approach are beyond the scope of this, but Qt implementation is good at least for the Qt Framework use, due to how signals and slots work (especially queued connections).

Comment: I wished they scrapped the Q prefix in the future though, that just destroys the poor q key. Just slam it all in a namespace for gods' sake.

Comment: @ddriver Well, that'd break all existing apps, so not going to happen. Also, I think many Qt coders really prefer writing `QSomething` to your hypothetical `Qt::Something`. Personal opinion: the `::` namespace notation of C++ sucks (two chars instead of one, looks ugly).

Comment: Sure, but it'd say if Qt plans on surviving long term, they will have to shed off all the legacy bloat in Qt 6. Otherwise things don't look "too Qt". And also, you can always `using namespace` and get a cozy little macro to spare yourself typing it everywhere.

Comment: @ddriver I'm not sure what "legacy bloat" you mean exactly (methods and classes get deprecated already), but considering the hassle of moving from Qt3 to Qt4, in contrast to moving from Qt4 to Qt5, I am pretty sure that if Qt6 broke source compatibility with Qt5 in a major way, it'd be dead on arrival. Most `QSomething` classes aren't going to go away. Going for namespace build by default might happen, but I don't know if there's any pressure for that, no practical issue it would solve (compared to current situation where you need to build Qt yourself if you want it in a namespace).

Comment: I mean the "60 mb of dlls" to deploy a basic application, I mean 1.7 gb of source files, full of redundancies and yet also huge gaping holes in functionality, I mean the "new issues introduced faster than old issues are fixed". The only reason Qt is being actively used to day is that there is practically no competition in that niche, but that also presents a very huge opportunity for some new framework, done from scratch. I honestly don't think Qt will make it without literally opening a new page.

Comment: Besides, I'd say it is a bad idea to use any particular framework directly - what makes sense is developing your own application API, and implementing it in a given framework. Then, when you want to migrate or upgrade, you just port that, much lesser effort than having to bother with backward compatibility of a third party product. Backward compatibility is actually a very bad thing when it resolves into an inefficient and tremendously bloated design.

Comment: @ddriver Qt5 increased modularization. Just don't include the modules you don't need, and the size is much smaller. Qt Core is under 5 MB, and getting rid of Qt containers etc in favor of C++ standard containers would probably shrink that by... 20% at most as a guess. Minimal Qt Quick app (one created by Qt Creator new project wizard) needs about 16 MB of Qt dynamic libraries. So replacing the Qt part with something leaner is not going to give you huge gains; whatever you replace it with is also going to take space. I partially agree with your sentiment, but not the solution you propose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127087/discussion-between-hyde-and-ddriver).

Answer (score 4):

That's because Qt predates the first C++ standard. Moreover, it wasn't until a few years later that you could reasonably expect various compilers to support the standard library without nasty corner cases. By that time Q-containers (and other classes, like QString) had a firm foothold in the codebase, and they provided functionality different enough that there was easy path for replacing them.

Answer (score 2):

To add on to the other answers, `QString` is fundamentally different than `std::string` because it's specifically designed to hold a Unicode string. While `std::string` can hold a Unicode string in UTF-8 encoding, some platforms (Windows for example) don't natively support UTF-8.

For historical reasons `QString` internally represents string data in UTF-16, but it has conversion methods to output the string data in other formats including UTF-8.

When building a Qt application it's best to stick with `QString` since all Qt APIs use it, and you won't have to deal with encoding/re-encoding from `std::string` or `std::wstring`, the later of which has different meanings across different platforms.

Comment: The type which corresponds to `std::string` is `QByteArray`. When dealing with 8 bit text in Qt, if there's no need to convert it to Unicode for processing, just keep it as the original `QByteArray` (received from socket or read from file or whatever), or convert to `std::string` directly if that's the type you want. In particular, if you don't know the encoding, you *can't* convert `QByteArray` to `QString` realiably.